# Websocket with Nextjs

Tags: websocket, next.js13

I am trying to make a websocket that gives real-time stock data every minute.

What I tried--

I have an API that gives stock data for every minute but to get this I need to call that API after each minute which makes http call every time.

To remove this process of calling API from the client side each minute I want to use WebSocket that will consume that API and call it at a minute interval at the backend and just emit the new array of stock data that the API returns.

Question in my mind--

1). Each user be able to get different data or not? For example, user1 wants stock data of Apple and user2 wants stock data of Tesla.

-->
I want to create socket with NextJs page routes. Any solution for this in node, express will work too.